# How to upload a file using an HTTP "PUT" using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, put

I would like to upload a file using JQuery-File-Upload, but using HTTP "PUT" instead of multipart-forms. [According to their site](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuery-File-Upload):

```
- Multipart and file contents stream uploads:
    Files can be uploaded as standard "multipart/form-data" or file contents stream (HTTP PUT file upload).
```

but I cannot find anywhere in their documentation as to how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812711/how-do-you-do-an-http-put

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

> method
>
> The method of the HTTP request used to
>   send the file(s) to the server. Can be
>   POST (multipart/formdata file upload)
>   or PUT (streaming file upload).
>   Accepts a String or a function
>   returning a String.

You should use :

```
$('#file_upload').fileUpload({
    namespace: 'file_upload_1',
    url: '/path/to/upload/handler.json',
    method: 'PUT'
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I looked at that page and still do not see from where you got. :'( Sorry, but it could be because I barely know JavaScript. In fact http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax has the field "type" mentioning PUT and GET.

Comment: updated answer. you set options when you intitilize your fileupload component

Comment: I definitely saw that before and just didn't understnad what it was saying. Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I love REST too but you might want to make sure you unit test well on the browsers you need to support.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they may not supported by older browsers.

See this answer
[How do I PUT data to Rails using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907910/how-do-i-put-data-to-rails-using-jquery)

Comment: PUT and DELETE are supported with ajax / jquery by all modern popular browsers, including even IE.  So, I think it's safe to use it in an Internet app.

Comment: This answer is nearly 5 year old, about time it was edited.