# Remotely deploying in Tomcat 7 using HTTP PUT

Tags: deployment, tomcat7, http-put

I want to remotely deploy my web app in Tomcat 7. I have added manager-gui, manager-text roles and added a user in conf/tomcat-users.xml. I checked this link out.
[Deploy A New Application Remotely](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely)
Here they have mentioned that we must upload the war file as HTTP PUT request. How do I achieve this ? I know there are ways to remotely deploy using ANT and Maven. But they look slightly complex to me. Using <form> with method="put" did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML FORM will only support GET and POST.  If you want to do this via a Web Interface I think [JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518420/how-to-upload-a-file-using-an-http-put-using-jquery) is the simplest route.  Taking the time to build it into your build and deploy process is probably the best solution though.