# Servlets upload file from form without enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

is there a possiblity to upload a file from html forms without using multipart/form-data?
I'm using Servlets 2.5 so I can't use getPart method and I still want to use getParameter method to get values from fields.

Comment: why not upload via PUT. same topic PUT with jquery : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518420/how-to-upload-a-file-using-an-http-put-using-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) Please read the example that shows how to get other request parameters apart from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use apache commons fileupload to handle mpe requests, like everyone else.

Comment: but when I use apache commons I have to use multipart/form-data which doesn't allow me to use getParameter method

Comment: Why not use Servlet  3.0 API?

Answer (score 0):

The `multipart/form-data` encoding type is a fundamental part of the HTML file upload mechanism - see for instance [the RFC where it was first standardised](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867), particularly this [section headed "File transfer with ENCTYPE=x-www-form-urlencoded"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867#section-5.8).

While there are other methods of uploading files now available (e.g. backed by Flash widgets) none of these can allow you to submit part of the form in normal `x-www-form-encoded` format but also attach uploaded files.

Perhaps you could write a wrapper object which wraps an API which supports `multipart/form-data` and implements the `getParameter` method you want on top of it for non-file fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `enctype` form attribute to upload files.

And since you're not using Servlet 3.0, you have to create your own filter if you want to keep using the `request.getParameter()` calls to get data from the input fields. You can find full examples [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/multipartfilter.html) and [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html).