# read files and add them to Owncloud using webdav

Tags: javascript, api, webdav, owncloud

I'm using Owncloud server 8, and it comes with webdav installed, i'm developping a web application with JavaScript/HTML5 and i want to access authentified user's files with webdav which i already can do with an Ajax request.

what i want to do is to add a file to my remote Owncloud server with webdav programatically using JavaScript, is that doable  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDav is designed to extend websites (for example enable saving), so it's fairly easy. If you want to add file, you make a PUT request, just like when you want to get a file from server, you make a GET request.

Samples (using JQuery):
adding simple text file - [JavaScript REST client Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921942/javascript-rest-client)
or: 
adding binary file - [How to upload a file using an HTTP "PUT" using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518420/how-to-upload-a-file-using-an-http-put-using-jquery)

If you really need a library, it's nice to take a look at: http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/. It costs approx. 550$, nevertheless their website is really cool, you can learn a lot from them, for example about clients, which will enable you to gain access to your files in Owncloud server:
http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/

Comment: Thank you, i have already found this, but your answer can be useful to other newbies like myself !