# HTML form PUT method

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

Because the server side only accepts PUT method, I used `method='PUT'` in the HTML form. But the browser didn't use method PUT as expected, it's `GET`. When I set `method='POST'` it's `POST`. 
I don't know why `method='PUT'` doesn't work. I have tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812711/how-do-you-do-an-http-put, this has some code examples.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Browsers only support `POST` and `GET`, if you need `PUT`, you have to send the form via post/get and then do the proper `PUT` request on server-side.

**EDIT** although, most implementations of XMLHttpRequest support `PUT` and `DELETE`.

Answer (score 17):

`PUT` is not recognized and is assimilated to `GET`.

Most frameworks use a hidden input to obtain `PUT` or `DELETE`:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```