# What is preferred way to submit form with express?

Tags: forms, node.js, express

In my first Node project [Express](http://expressjs.com/)/[Express-resource](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource) libraries are used and [Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) for templating.

According to [docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource) default mappings are generated. Among them we can find:

```
PUT     /forums/:forum       ->  update
```

Yet, I do not see easy way to submit values.

**How to submit creation/update?**

Jade form can be created easily and body parser as well, but how to submit this form? Please note that express-resource defines **PUT** method (not POST).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#http-methods):

> When using methods such as PUT with a form, we can utilize a hidden input named _method, which can be used to alter the HTTP method. To do so we first need the methodOverride middleware, which should be placed below bodyParser so that it can utilize it’s req.body containing the form values.

So:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

And in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
```

**Update:** As I understand the new comments from the asker, nrph wants a way to submit a form with the `PUT` method, using ajax. Here is a solution using jQuery:

```
// Use this submit handler for all forms in document
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  // Form being submitted
  var form = e.currentTarget;
  // Issue an ajax request
  $.ajax({
    url: form.action,          // the forms 'action' attribute
    type: 'PUT',               // use 'PUT' (not supported in all browsers)
                               // Alt. the 'method' attribute (form.method)
    data: $(form).serialize(), // Serialize the form's fields and values
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {}
  });
  // Prevent the browser from submitting the form
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Aren't these put mappings created to be handled in ajax way?

Comment: Excuse me? I don't understand the question.

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7257509/450441 comment most modern browsers support PUT with XMLHttpRequest. So it gives an idea that maybe ajax should be the most obvious option to submit values with express.

Comment: Oh sure, if your browser can issue a `PUT` this is a non-issue.

Comment: So you are suggesting just to use POST?

Comment: I'm suggesting you use `POST` (which is cross-browser compatible) with a hidden `_method` parameter set to `put`, which together with the `methodOverride` middleware will resolve to your `PUT` handler.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your insights. I seemed strange that creators of express-resource didn't create the most obvious POST mappings. As a express rookie I'm still looking for reason behind that.

Comment: You're still confused. Express provides that through `methodOverride`. Can't really do much about browsers only having support for `GET` and `POST`.

Comment: That preventDefault() needs to be the first statement or the form will still submit.