# Why is a servicestack service routing to GET instead of PUT

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I was given permission to study ServiceStack this week.  I love it.  It is an amazing framework.  But I have run into a situation where I cannot get a fairly straight-forward example to work.  (Although it is admittedly not as straightforward as the examples but is probably more realistic an example.)

Apologies in advance for this long question.

I have a simple DTO that maps to a database like this...

```
[Description("Customer")]
[Alias("Customers")]
    public class Customer : IHasId<int>
    {
        [Alias("Id")]
        [AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set;}

        [Required]
        public int CompanyId { get; set;}

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set;}

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set;}

        public string MiddleInitial { get; set;}
        public string EmployerName { get; set;}
        public string ServiceLocationDescription { get; set;}
        public string Street1 { get; set;}
        public string Street2 { get; set;}
        public string City { get; set;}
        public string State { get; set;}
        public string Zip { get; set;}

        [Required]
        public string Phone { get; set;}
        public string Fax { get; set;}

        [Required]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set;}
    }
}
```

I have also created Request DTOs that look like this...

```
//request dto
[Route("/customers/{companyId/customer/{customerId}", "GET")]
public class GetCustomer  : Customer
{
}

[Route("/customers/{companyId}/customer/{customerId}", "PUT")]
public class UpdateCustomer  : Customer
{
}
```

I realize the routes are the same...thats probably the issue...but I am designating different http methods....

Finally I have a service that looks like this...

```
public CustomerResponse Get(GetCustomer request)
{
    return new CustomerResponse { Customer = customerRepository.GetCustomer(request.CustomerId), };
}

public object Put(UpdateCustomer request)
{
    customerRepository.UpdateCustomer(request);
    return new HttpResult
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent,
        Headers = {
            { HttpHeaders.Location, this.RequestContext.AbsoluteUri.CombineWith(request.Id.ToString()) }
        }
    };
}
```

So to test it out I created the following simple html...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="http://localhost:8080/co/1/customers/1000" method="get">
    <br />
    <label id="Label1">CompanyId&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="CompanyId" type="text" /></label><br />
    FirstName&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="FirstName" type="text" /><br />
    LastName&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="LastName" type="text" /><br />
    Middle Initial&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    **OTHER FIELDS**  
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

All of this is working great only the PUT is routing to the GET service.

My goal is to update the customer row with new values of course.

I am not showing the customer repository class but that is working fine.  I guess. I have a specific an general questions.

How do I route to the PUT intstead of the GET.  And is there a "best practice" for using the service to do an update.  For example...should the PUT service not recieve a customer object but rather all of the values...then the repo code fetches the record and does the udpate?

The POST method (not shown) works great BTW.  It is exactly like the PUT method (recieves a Customer object etc)

**EDIT**

I also just determined that my attempt to use DELETE http method also routes to GET.  That is a simple type that does not even inherit from Customer.  It just get two delete parameters.   Now I am really baffled.

**EDIT 2**

It seems to only be routing to service methods that return concrete types.  The exception is the POST which returns object...Get returns a customer reponse object.  Get Customers returns a Customers(plural)Response object and works.  The rest of the service methods are returning object.  Is that it?

Comment: `[Route("/customers/{companyId/customer/{customerId}", "PUT")]` <-- You're missing a closing `}` in the route.  Not sure if that's a typo or if that's the actual root cause of the issue.  But worth fixing and letting us know.

Comment: Also your method uses a class called `UpdateCustomer` but your example calls it `PutCustomer`

Comment: Eli...sharp eyes.  They were just typos though.  I have fixed them in the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257481/html-form-put-method I reckon this is it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Browser's don't support PUT/DELETE as Eli pointed out. Should be able to get it to work with ServiceStack using `X-HTTP-Method-Override` as an input field. @mythz stole my thunder and added support for it [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/563057a8af37cad14f9a7240683f71e0e8792181) (not bitter about him beating me to this)

Also your `<form>` method is 'get' which should always route to your ServiceStack's Service 'Get' method.

Untested, but I think this should work.

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/co/1/customers/1000" method="POST">
    <br />
    <input name="X-HTTP-Method-Override" type="hidden" value="PUT" />
    <label id="Label1">CompanyId&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="CompanyId" type="text" /></label><br />
    FirstName&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="FirstName" type="text" /><br />
    LastName&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="LastName" type="text" /><br />
    Middle Initial&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    **OTHER FIELDS**  
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```