# Is the REST method the same as the method attribute sent by the form element in an HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms, rest

I have read everything I can find about REST style URIs and its noun and verbs, GET, POST, PUT, etc. What I did not see is where I put those methods to begin with. I can only find the back end PHP.

Is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` looking at what I put here `<form action="something.php" method="PUT">`?

And from there I use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to process it with `switch` or some other construct?

I think that's what this is saying, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

---

<sub>Seems you have to put it in a [hidden value somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257481/html-form-put-method).</sub>

Comment: REST is a style or mode of client-server interaction; it's not a prescription for programming. The [Wikipedia article on REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) might help shed some light on things, particularly the [section on architectural constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints).

Comment: You can only make GET and POST requests with an html form, not PUT or DELETE.

Comment: You can use the other verbs with a library like cURL. GET and POST are the same HTTP verbs regardless of how they're requested.

Comment: further reading: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: @Steve I didn't not read every word, but I didn't see where the PUT is put to get to the server to begin with.

Comment: Sorry @johnny im not following you. Whatever client you are using (cURL, javascript ajax, any other http lib, **not an html form**) will have an option to set the request method