# System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes introducing weird character

Tags: c#

Performing a PUT to a client web service using this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = "<xml>...</xml>";
        byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/");
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = arr.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string returnString = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(returnString);
    }
}
```

Courtesy of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812711/how-do-you-do-an-http-put)

If I look at the request in fiddler there is a strange character at the end of my post request `</xml>` looks like a square[suspect its a BOM]

not sure how it got introduced i my string.

Comment: The default `UTF8.GetBytes` does not include a BOM, and if you ask for one it is added to the front of the array not the end. The code you posted does not include a “strange character” in my test so something else is going on. Are you doing anything else to `arr`? Copy the “strange character” and look at it in a hex editor.

Comment: How you creating xml string? Example if you are using XmlWriter then you need to set like this: `new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false) }`

Answer (score 2):

Use `new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(xml);`

[UTF8Encoding Constructor (Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx): Initializes a new instance of the UTF8Encoding class. A parameter specifies whether to provide a Unicode byte order mark.

Comment: Tried that but the weird square still exists at end of my xml data in fiddler.